# Nonetype error/ No elements printed using beautifulsoup for python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

So im trying to compare 2 lists using python, one contains like 1000 links i fetched from a website. The other one contains a few words, that might be contained in a link in the first list. If this is the case, i want to get an output. i printed that first list, it actually works. for example if the link is "https://steamcdn-a.swap.gg/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/eslkatowice2015/counterlogic.f49adabd6052a558bff3fe09f5a09e0675737936.png" and my list contains the word "eslkatowice2015", i want to get an output using the `print()` function. My code looks like this:

```
page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
Bot_Stickers = soup.find_all('img', class_='csi')

for sticker in Bot_Stickers:

    for i in StickerIDs:

        if i in sticker:

            print("found")
driver.close()
```

now the problem is that i dont get an output, which is impossible because if i manually compare the lists, there are clearly elements from the first list existing in the 2nd list (the one with the links). when trying to fix i always got a NoneType error. The driver.page_source is above defined by some selenium i used to access a site and click some javascript stuff, to be able to find everything. I hope its more or less clear what i wanted to reach

Edit: the StickerIDs variable is the 2nd list containing the words i want to be checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoneType` error means that you might be [getting a `None` somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something#:%7E:text=10%20Answers&text=NoneType%20means%20that%20instead%20of,or%20returned%20an%20unexpected%20result.), so it's probably safer to check the results returned by `find_all` for `None`.

It's been a while since is used BeautifulSoup, but If I remember correctly, `find_all` returns a list of `beautiful soup tags` that match the search criteria, not URLs. You need to get the `href` attribute from the tag before checking if it contains a keyword.

Something like that:

```
page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
Bot_Stickers = soup.find_all('img', class_='csi')

if Bot_Stickers and StickersIDs:
 
    for sticker in Bot_Stickers:
        for i in StickerIDs:
            if i in sticker.get("href"): # get href attribute of the img tag
                print("found")
else:
    print("Bot_Stickers:", Bot_Stickers)
    print("StickersIDs:" StickersIDs)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Tried it right now with the other script, as i tried before, i also get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\timjo\Desktop\BOTSCRIPT\Bot.py", line 27, in <module>
    if i in sticker.get("href"):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
not sure how to solve that

Comment: @Timeler The error says trying to iterate over a None, so check both `Bot_Stickers` and `StickersIDs` before the for loops. It's a good and safe practice to check for values that might break your code. Once you know which one is `None`, you should start debugging why you're getting a `None` instead of, say, a list of tags. I've updated the answer.

Comment: if i try it as you edited the solution, i get the same error as before. if i replace the sticker.get("href"): by sticker i get no error but no output either, so either way it doesnt do what it should

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. That means the `<img>` tag has not attribute named `href`. You should check the HTML source, and see what's the attribute name that has the image link, it could be something like `src`. After that, change `href` to the attribute name that has the image link in it, and it should work.